# Crash UIScrollView EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, cocoa, uiscrollview, uikit, exc-bad-access

I'm having trouble to diagnostic a crash with UIScrollView

```
UIKit
-[UIScrollView setContentOffset:]
```

Exception Type: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` Code `KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS` at 0xe0000008

```
com.apple.main-thread Crashed
0    libobjc.A.dylib     objc_msgSend + 15
1    UIKit   -[UIScrollView setContentOffset:] + 618
2    UIKit   -[UITableView setContentOffset:] + 330
3    UIKit   -[UIScrollView(Static) _adjustContentOffsetIfNecessary] + 1474
4    UIKit   -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _stopScrollingNotify:pin:tramplingDragFlags:] + 414
5    UIKit   -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _stopScrollingNotify:pin:] + 30
6    UIKit   -[UIScrollView removeFromSuperview] + 30
7 ...    UIKit   -[UIView dealloc] + 296
8    UIKit   -[UIView dealloc] + 296
9    libobjc.A.dylib     (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 168
10   CoreFoundation  _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 16
11   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 1296
12   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
13   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
14   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 74
15   UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 1120
16   iTV Shows  main.m line 12
```

Comment: My psychic powers are failing me, so I cannot see your code to try to determine the problem.

Comment: I'll show you the code, but I don't know where it's happening. There is only call from UIKit, CoreFoundation but no call from the code...

Comment: It looks like you aren't using ARC, and that you are overreleasing an autoreleased object.

Comment: I do use ARC. I'm sorry if I have no more informations, it's a crash report I'm getting from crashlytics. I don't even know how to reproduce it. I just thought it worth the shot to ask. :)

Comment: Any luck solving this issue? Think I've hit the same problem.

Comment: Same problem as well. using ARC as well.  From what I'm getting in my stack trace (and yours b/c they're almost identical) is that a table view is being removed from the super view, and that it's delegate is being called after the view has been removed

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Setting the `TableView` and `ScrollView` delegates (or any other delegates that you might have) to nil in the `dealloc` method solved the problem.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    self.tableView.delegate = nil;
    self.tableView.dataSource = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to give a concrete answer without seeing your code, but the [iOS Debugging Magic](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2239/_index.html) technical note is always a great resource with tips for debugging crashes.

> [Technical Note TN2239: iOS Debugging Magic](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2239/_index.html)